# How do I remove specific element from an array?

Tags: perl

I have 2 arrays. One will contain things I want to delete and the other will be the main array.

so lets say

```
my @main_array = ("apple","bob","cat","dog","earth");
my @stuff_to_delete_array = ("bob","dog");
```

I want the final main_array to have `("apple","cat","earth")`. Lets say I don't know the index. Is there a way to search for `"bob"` and `"dog"` in the main_array and remove them?

Comment: You didn't tried anything... Lot of answers in the search engine.

Answer (score 4):

```
my @items = ( "apple", "bob", "cat", "dog", "earth" );
my @to_delete = ( "bob", "dog" );

# Create a hash for quick lookup
my %to_delete = map { $_ => 1 } @to_delete;

my @filtered = grep { !$to_delete{$_} } @items;
```

This solution preserves the order of the items in `@items`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the module `Array::Utils`. This module supports to delete the elements which we can compare two array elements.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.010;
use Array::Utils qw(:all);

my %cmp = ();

my @main_array = ("apple","bob","cat","dog","earth");
my @stuff_to_delete_array = ("bob","dog");

my @output = array_minus(@main_array, @stuff_to_delete_array);
print join "\n", @output;
```

You can just try this.

Answer (score 1):

Translating the array to a hash may come handy here:

```
my %h;
@h{ @main_array } = ();
delete @h{ @stuff_to_delete_array };
@main_array = keys %h;
```

Comment: Note: This solution doesn't preserve the order of the items in `@items`. That may or may not be imporant.

Comment: I mean `@main_array`